# What's the best type to pass as a "run this code when required" method?

Tags: java, android, runnable

Currently I've been passing `Runnables` from my Main class to other classes. For example I'll pass a `Runnable` from my Main into another class which has a `Button` and then set the `Button`'s `onClickListener` to run that `Runnable` whenever the `Button` is clicked. Is this something I should avoid doing or even if not, is there something better that I could pass so that I can run a selection of code using variables from my Main without having to actually pass my Main class into other classes?

Since it's not very clear, there is no issue, I just wanted to know if creating a new Runnable every time I want to run a bit of code in different classes was a bad idea.

Comment: "without having to actually pass my Main class into other classes" - are you passing your Main class or are you passing Runnables. I'm not sure I can understand your issue.

Comment: @alfasin I'm passing `Runnables`.

Comment: Then what's the issue ?

Comment: See the title, Runnables from what I know are related to Threads so I want to know if it's something that I should avoid creating hundreds of.

Comment: hundreds ? do you have hundreds of buttons ?

Comment: There's no issue, I just want to know what's the best type of thing to pass for the same kind of fuction.

Comment: @alfasin No not currently but it may end up like that.

Comment: As you said Runnable are designed to specific (or not) Thread running operations. In your case, no need to involve that kind of class.

Comment: If you use latest Android Studio, you can use Java8 and lambdas and actually what you describe is a common use case for them. Through the closure, you can even transparently access fields and local final vars from your main class in your lambda expressions.

Comment: Just stay with Runnable. And if the code is short enough, use a lambda expression to make it more concise.

Comment: Runnables are "related to threads" only in that you can send a runnable off to execute on its own thread. That isn't how they're usually employed for callbacks. The only thing to watch out for (and this applies to any interface used) is whether you're holding unnecessary references in them.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface, use it as a callback parameter or your class containing your button.

This interface can also be an implementation of View.OnClickListener, depends of what you really need to do.

```
interface OnSubClassButtonClickListener {
    void onClick();
}

OnSubClassButtonClickListener listener = new OnSubClassButtonClickListener () {
    void onClick() {
         // Your code here
    }
}

void init() {
    SubClass subClass1 = new SubClass(listener);
    SubClass subClass2 = new SubClass(listener);
}

class SubClass {

    private OnSubClassButtonClickListener listener;
    private Button button;

    SubClass(OnSubClassButtonClickListener listener) {
        button = //...
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             void onClick(View view) {
                  if (listener == null) {
                      return;
                  }
                  listener.onClick();
             }
        });

    }


}
```